# Collect steps run time in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

Is there a way to collect stats from GitHub Actions, like the time it takes to run each step in a job? Either via GitHub API or an action itself?

Comment: There are webhooks triggered when a job starts and ends. Does that suffice?